# FieldError: Relation fields do not support nested lookups

Tags: python, django

Estou tentando fazer uma *query* no Django com vários *joins*, e me deparei com esse erro que não sei o que significa:

```
Tag.objects.filter(dset__descendant__entities__entity=e)
```

> FieldError: Relation fields do not support nested lookups

Meus modelos nessa *query* são `Tag`, `Entity`, `TaggedEntity` e `EntityClosure` (é um modelo tipo EAV, [código completo aqui](https://bitbucket.org/mgibsonbr/difutils/src/51ab1854c5d6032cd569c13b9a233368a2361280/difutils_eav/models.py?at=default)). Eles representam o seguinte:

1. `Entity` é uma entidade. Tudo o que ela tem são campos "nome" e "detalhes":

   ```
   class Entity(models.Model):
       name = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
       details = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
   ```
2. `EntityClosure` é uma tabela de relacionamentos (as entidades formam uma árvore):

   ```
   class EntityClosure(Model):
       ancestor = models.ForeignKey(Entity, related_name="dset")
       descendant = models.ForeignKey(Entity, related_name="aset")
       depth = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
   ```
3. `Tag` é uma "etiqueta" associada a uma entidade. Cada entidade pode possuir várias etiquetas, e as etiquetas em si também são entidades (i.e. elas também formam uma árvore):

   ```
   class Tag(Entity):
       pass

   class TaggedEntity(Model):
       entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity,related_name="tags")
       tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag,related_name="entities")
   ```

Minha *query* desejada é: "selecione todas as etiquetas associadas a uma entidade"...

```
Tag.objects.filter(entities__entity=e) # Funciona
```

..."mas levando em conta a hierarquia" (i.e. busque também as tags que são ancestrais das tags associadas à entidade):

```
Tag.objects.filter(dset__descendant__entities__entity=e) # Erro
```

Eu não vejo nada de errado nessa query... mas algum problema está acontecendo entre o `descendant` e o `entities` que não permite que ela seja feita. O estranho é que se eu fizer duas queries ele aceita numa boa:

```
>>> conj = [x.ancestors for x in Tag.objects.filter(entities__entity=d).annotate(ancestors=F('aset__ancestor'))]
>>> conj
[3, 1, 3, 1]
>>> Tag.objects.filter(pk__in=conj)
[<Tag: TipoDocumento>, <Tag: Recibo Fiscal>]
```

[Aqui está um MCVE](http://pastebin.com/JLvuT3ih), se quiserem testar (o código real é bem mais extenso).

Note também que - conforme [esse exemplo no SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5e3f9/11/0) mostra - a query que eu quero fazer não é nada de mais, só não sei por que o Django está com dificuldades de montá-la:

```sql
select t.*
from tagged_entity te
  join entity_closure ec on te.tag = ec.descendant
  join entity t on t.id = ec.ancestor
where te.entity = 1;
```

Então... o que significa esse `FieldError` apresentado, e como posso contorná-lo para fazer o que eu quero com uma única query?

---

**Atualização:** após atualizar para o Django 1.11 a mensagem de erro mudou:

> FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: entities

Que é um tantinho mais descritiva do que a mensagem anterior. Possivelmente o erro está em usar `__entities` - uma relação de `Tag` - logo após `__descendant` - uma relação de `EntityClosure` - já que `EntityClosure` não se relaciona com `Tag`, mas sim com `Entity`. Isso também explicaria por que a solução com duas queries funciona: pois o resultado da primeira seria um conjunto de ids de *entities*, não de *tags*...

Comment: Você está tentando acessar `dset` diretamente da `Tag` sem haver relacionamento, ou estou enganado?

Comment: @Orion Não entendi. `dset` é o `related_name` do campo `EntityClosure.ancestor`. Eu consigo acessá-lo normalmente (ex.: `Tag.objects.filter(dset__descendant=4)` retorna todos os ancestrais da tag de id `4`). O problema está entre o `descendant` e o `entities` segundo meus testes, mas posso estar enganado.

Comment: Não sabia que ao herdar criava esse relacionamento, por isso estranhei.

Comment: @Orion Sim. Pelo que pude constatar, se um modelo `Tag` herda de um modelo `Entity`, então a tabela que representa a tag vai ter, em vez de um campo `id`, um campo `entity_ptr` ou algo assim, que é ao mesmo tempo chave primária e chave estrangeira pra tabela mãe. Dessa forma, todas as relações de outras tabelas com a tabela mãe também são aplicáveis ao modelo filho, já que este é representado por uma linha na tabela mãe e uma linha na tabela filha (possuindo todas as colunas de ambas), com a mesma chave primária.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, lendo o último comentário sobre a criação da tabela mãe, caso você não queria que essa tabela seja criada, você deve colocar um class Meta: abstract = True em Entity. Nisso o django não cria a tabela mãe e todos os campos dela ficariam na tabela Tag no seu caso. Isso diminuiria o número de joins a serem feitos. Mas teria que rever a modelagem em EntityClosure que possui a foreignkey para Entity

Comment: @PuamDias Infelizmente é importante pra mim sim que a tabela Entity exista (pois são elementos dela que receberão a tag). E de todo modo meu objetivo não é reduzir o número de joins (minha consulta real tem ainda mais joins rsrs), e sim resolver esse problema de não conseguir montar a query. Se não tiver solução, beleza, posso viver com duas queries em vez de uma, mas o ideal seria fazer a consulta inteira numa query só (e como pode-se ver no SQL de exemplo, não é nada do outro mundo...).

Answer (score 2):

Me parece que seu problema surge da herança entre os models `Tag`e `Entity`.

Eu acho que, dada essa estrutura de models, o Django deriva a seguinte estrutura de tabelas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, a herança entre os models `Tag` e `Entity` geraria duas tabelas diferentes, porém estruturalmente iguais.

Porém, no model `EntityClosure`, você só define FK's para `Entity`, e não para `Tag`. Então você só poderia usar o related_name `dset` no model `Entity`. Usá-lo no `Tag`, como você está tentando fazer, gera o erro apresentado.

Comment: Infelizmente o problema não é esse. Se um modelo é abstrato e outro modelo herda dele, então sim, o Django copia a estrutura do modelo base pro modelo derivado. Mas como `Entity` é um modelo concreto, a tabela relativa ao modelo `Tag` não contém campos `name` e `details`, apenas um campo `entity_ptr` que referencia `Entity.id`. E segundo o ORM do Django, eu posso sim usar `dset` no modelo `Tag`, por exemplo fazendo `Tag.objects.filter(dset__descendant=e)` (que funciona como esperado).

Comment: De todo modo, eu agradeço pela sugestão, pois você está certo numa coisa - estando o `EntityClosure` ligado a `Entity` e não a `Tag`, o resultado de `dset__descendant` é um `Entity`, e talvez por isso ele não suporte chamar `__entities` logo em seguida (já que é uma relação de `Tag`). Talvez a resposta para o problema esteja mesmo aí...

Answer (score 0):

Tente não usar **alias** em seus joins porque dependendo da engine da sua database ou da versão da base de dados ele não aplica às correlatas. Caso use **alias** coloque sempre a sintaxe **as** na frente do nome da tabela / campo que você deseja por o **alias**.

Especifique sempre o seu tipo de join, não dê apenas join, tente sempre usar inner, left ou qualquer predecessor relacional para especificar detalhadamente o tipo de relacionamento que você busca na sua query.

Exemplo:

```
   select t.*
from tagged_entity
  inner join entity_closure on tagged_entity.tag = entity_closure.descendant
  join entity as t on t.id = tagged_entity.ancestor
where tagged_entity.entity = 1;
```

Outra coisa que eu reparei que os nomes dos dados da sua tabela e a forma que você faz a relação entre eles é bem inconsistente deixando até o confuso o entendimento para terceiros (para o criado obviamente é claro, porque foi ele que criou).

Sugiro que sempre que você for carregar alguma **foreign key** para outra tabela sempre colocar o **nome da tabela + campo que você está carregando**, exemplo:

Você tem a tabela usuario, com categorias que outra tabela

Então você teria a tabela user com o campo foreign key category_id / id_category, nunca **jamais** usar nomes genericos em sua base, aparemente mesmo sua query parece bem normal e estruturada corretamente, mas em termos de leitura, está horrível, e o django no momento da montagem não está conseguindo montar corretamente as correlatas relacionais, sugiro que você faça outros testes genericos com tabelas estruturadas para averiguar se realmente o problema no código ou se a base de dados está mal estrutura.

Comment: Mas foi o próprio Django que criou a estrutura das tabelas, como ele pode estar tendo dificuldade em montar o que ele mesmo criou?! Quanto ao SQL, acho que você não entendeu, isso foi só um exemplo mostrando que a query que eu quero fazer não é nada de mais. O problema é que o ORM do Django não está conseguindo fazer uma consulta semelhante. Minha pergunta se refere ao erro específico mencionado, no ORM, não no SQL. Eu agradeço suas sugestões quanto à portabilidade do código e nomenclatura, mas infelizmente o problema aqui é outro.

Comment: Entendi, nesse caso você tem terá que fazer as queries manualmente para evitar esses problemas da ORM, outro dia tava com o mesmo problema no flask que ele montava as queries de forma "incorreta" (devido a muitos relacionamentos), logo tive que faze-las manualmente.